# System.ArgumentException: 'No mapping exists from object type System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker to a known managed provider native type.'

Tags: c#

```
con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=N:\ASI report\asiemp.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;");
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO salestable (salesid,empid,salesdate,revenu,gp,shipping) values(next value for MyFirstSequence, @empid, @salesdate, @revenu, @gp, @shipping) ", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@empid", txtempid.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@salesdate", datep1);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@revenu", txtrev.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@gp", txtgp.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@shipping", txtship.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: there is a reason why `SqlParameterCollection.Add(string, Object)` is deprecated: it is easy to get wrong. better use [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s(v=vs.110).aspx) and set the value separately.

Comment: `'No mapping exists from object type System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker to a known managed provider native type.'` Which parameter are you passing in of that type?

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@salesdate", datep1);
```

tries to create a parameter whose value is a DateTimePicker. The Sql Server doesn't know what a DateTimePicker is. You need the DateTime value of the DateTimePicker

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@salesdate", datep1.Value);
```

Also I recommend you to use the overload of Parameters.Add where you can specify the datatype of the parameter

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@salesdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = datep1.Value;
```